# Base class and derived class cannot both have a private nested class with the same name?

Tags: c#

I have a base and derived class; both of which have a nested class. The nested classes have the same name as each other but are private. I'd like to know why this doesn't work.

In my case, the nested classes are solely for internal organization. The nested class's name is `Properties`. I've tried marking the derived class's `Properties` member as `new` where it was declared, but Visual Studio says there isn't a member for it to override.

Here's an abbreviated example of my structure.

```
class SomeBaseEditor : Editor
{
    private class Properties
    {
        // properties specific to the base gui stored in here
    }

    private Properties properties = new Properties ();

    protected virtual void OnEnable ()
    {
        properties = new Properties (serializedObject);
    }
}
```

```
public class SomeBaseEditorImplementation : SomeBaseEditor
{
    private class Properties
    {
        // properties specific to the implementation's gui stored in here
    }
    // tried marking this as new, but Visual Studio said it wasn't hiding a member
    private Properties properties = new Properties ();

    protected override void OnEnable ()
    {
        properties = new Properties (serializedObject);
    }
}
```

This code is for a custom editor in Unity. The interesting thing is, the error is thrown *after* compilation - when the actual code runs.

When the base class tries to access a member in it's `properties` instance, a null reference exception is thrown. I didn't think this should throw an error as both classes are private and cannot be accessed from anywhere.

If I break on the error and hover over the `properties` variable, Visual Studio shows it contains the members from the derived class's nested private class!?

I'll elaborate with an example from my case. The base `Properties` class has a single `SerializedProperty` inside it. The derived class's `Properties` class has five `SerializedProperty`s. When I break on the **base class's** `properties` instance (where the error is thrown) it shows that it contains the 5 `SerializedProperty`s from it's **derived class**!

Here's what I see in Visual Studio:
[image]

So it's trying to access a member in a class that doesn't even have the member declared. I'm amazed this error isn't triggered at compile-time and would like to know why it doesn't work in the first place.

Here's links to simplified versions of my two classes that may give more context to the problem that my highly abbreviated example

- Base Class: https://hastebin.com/ifezubuqav.cs
- Derived Class: https://hastebin.com/cohuyaseci.cs

Comment: It is perfectly ok (confusing, but ok) to do that. Some other code that you don't show is not behaving the way you expect but it is not possible to reason about it without [MCVE]. At least some more complete version of the classes may help

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe my example code, within the context of it being Unity editor code, fully encompasses the problem. However, I'll add links to simplified versions of my code as it's always possible my example is missing something important.

Comment: like your screenshot showing `properties` assigned in some sort of `OnEnable` method (that may or may not get called probably) while your sample shows `properties` assigned all the time before constructor.

Comment: In the image I linked you can see that `properties` is not null where the error is thrown, but you are right that could have been relevant, I'll update my code example to be more clear where the field is initialized. I think at this point it is clearly a problem with Unity, and likely how it serializes the Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derived class's initialization method `OnEnable` overrode the base class's `OnEnable` without calling the base method so the base class's `properties` variable was never assigned. It's still odd that Visual Studio didn't say the variable was null, but by changing the derived class's `OnEnable` method to call `base.OnEnable` the errors went away.

```
protected override void OnEnable ()
{
    base.OnEnable ();
    properties = new Properties (serializedObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really haven't provided [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That being said I have no difficulty having a base class and a derived class each with a *duplicate* class with the same name and property with the same name.

[DotNetFiddle Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u4pSsO)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var foo2 = new Foo2();
    foo2.Foo1Go();  //Write "1"
    foo2.Foo2Go();  //Writes "2" then "1"
}

public class Foo1
{
    private class Bar { public int Id { get; private set; } = 1; }
    
    private Bar bar = new Bar();
    
    public void Foo1Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Id);
    }
}

public class Foo2 : Foo1
{
    private class Bar { public int Id { get; private set; } = 2; }
    
    private Bar bar = new Bar();

    public void Foo2Go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Id);
        var foo1 = this as Foo1;
        foo1.Foo1Go();
    }
}
```

Results

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 1

Comment: It looks like you are right, the C# code isn't doing anything wrong hence it compiling. The only "unknown" remaining is the fact that it is running inside Unity. I have a feeling this is a problem with Unity serializing the editors which are ScriptableObjects.